# How do I use cmd+1 as a keyboard shortcut? cmd+2, cmd+3, etc, work

Tags: iterm

In Preferences > Profiles > Keys
I've mapped <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> but <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> alone does not respond.

Does anyone else have this issue?

This is for the latest iterm2, v2.1.1 and several earlier versions as well; it has never worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [OS X Keyboard Shortcuts,](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) you will see that the keystroke Command-1 through 4 are already assigned to finder which means 5 through 9 are available for mapping.

And speaking of which...OS X once allowed you to create your own mappings and that feature seems to have been conveniently removed.  I reccomend taking a look at [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)  which will not only allow you to remap your keys, but also change all the related settings.  Karabiner should allow you to change the mappings of Command-1 through 4 as well.

Comment: Karabiner seems great. I havn't actually created the keymap I need yet, just looking through docs. I'd like cmd+1 to map to ctrl+b 1 for tmux.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that **iterm2** uses <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> ... etc for switching between tabs by default. As long as you have first tab, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is binded to switch to the this tab.

Workaround is to change *Keys -> Navigation shortcuts -> To switch tabs:* value to <kbd>alt</kbd> or any other except <kbd>cmd</kbd>.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used iTerm but it sounds like the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> might be used somewhere else in your system. Try looking inside System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and look around to see if the shortcut you want to use is already taken by the system or another application.

Answer (score -1):

iTerm2 → Preferences → key → Navigation Shortcuts → To switch split panes.
Replace it with other keys, then <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> will work.

Comment: How does this differ from an existing information with the same information?